# get post excerpt by query

Tags: plugins, posts, query-posts, code

I'm trying to get post excerpt by query my code is below

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT post_title, post_excerpt 
FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND (post_type = 'post') 
AND post_content LIKE '%My Text%' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
```

but it show only title of post and wrong excerpt...

any help

Answer (score 0):

You're querying post_content but selecting post_excerpt. These two things are not the same.

Perhaps the text you are searching for is in more than one post?

Comment: yes i need more than one post!

Comment: So, as i said - excerpt and content are different things. Just because you find some text in the content, that doesnt mean it will be in the post_excerpt field.